# Use single-pole voltage detector to check for currentflow on a lamp

Tags: measurement, voltage-measurement, lamp

I am using a single-pole voltage detector to detect if there is a current-flow / potential on the clamps of my ceiling lamp (See device in first picture below).

When the ceiling-lamp is ON and glowing, and I measure with the single-pole voltage detector, the detectors indicator lamp starts glowing, when I measure on phase (L), telling me there is a potential. -like expected.

If I measure the neutral conductor (N), my detector is NOT glowing.
But since my ceiling lamp is turned on and glowing, there is also power on my neutral cable (N), so I would expect my detector lamp to start glowing as well.

My Question: Why can my my single-pole voltage detector not detect the current-flow on my neutral cable (N)?

My assumption is the following:
When I measure on the phase-clamp (L), my detector is parallel to the lamp and also to my source voltage. Means it gets 230 V (See second picture below "1 Measure parallel"), so it can detect the potential.

When I measure on the neutral-clamp, I measure in serial to the lamp, but parallel to a short-circuit. So my Lamp gets 230 V, but my single-pole voltage detector gets pretty much 0 V (See last picture below "2 Measure serial").

Is this assumption correct? If not, what is the reason that my detector does not detect the potential of my lamp, which is turned on and glowing?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those things detect a voltage difference between ground and the connected wire.  Your body makes the connection to ground - that's why you must touch the contact on the end of it.

The neutral wire in your house is connected to ground - the literal ground beneath your feet and the ground (green) wire in your house wiring.

There is (ideally) no voltage difference between neutral and ground.  In practice, there's usually a few (maybe a few tens) of volts difference between neutral and ground.  Not enough for the detector to notice.

There's 230V between hot and neutral, but zero between neutral and ground.

If you touch a supposed neutral wire with your detector and it lights up, then you should stop working on your wiring - there is something is wrong, and it could kill you.  If your detector lights up on a neutral wire, have your wiring checked by an electrician before you do anything else with the wiring.

---

The detectors are simple, and they fail "safe."  That is, if they break you will not be electrocuted while using it.

What can happen, though, is that they fail and don't detect a hot wire.

I always check the detector before doing anything on the wiring.

1. Turn on lights
2. Touch the detector to the hot wire.  It should light up.
3. Turn off lights.
4. Touch detector to the hot wire.  It should not light up.

If you touch the detector to a supposed hot wire and it doesn't light up, then you should check it again on a known good hot wire (like an outlet.)  If it still doesn't light up, it is broken.  They are cheap, buy a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your explaination makes total sense to me, if we would talk about a power socket. The potential between (L) and (N) (or Ground) is ~230 V, so I can detect it. The potential between (N) and Ground should be 0 V, so I can not detect  it. But if I have a connected lamp, which is also turned on (see image above "2 Measure parallel"), I am measuring parallel to a short-circuit, right? So even with the lamp being turned on and I measure on (N), my detector will not detect anything, because I measure the difference between neutral and ground.

Comment: A light bulb is **not** a short circuit.  If light bulbs were short circuits, then you would blow a fuse in your house every time you turn one on.  The old fashioned filament light bulbs are more like a resistor.  Their resistance is high enough that only maybe half of an ampere will flow.  Not a  short circuit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to JRE's answer:

> I am using a single-pole voltage detector to detect if there is a current-flow / potential on the clamps of my ceiling lamp ...

You can't use a *voltage detector* to monitor current. As the name suggests, it measures voltage. It has no idea whether or not current is flowing in that part of the circuit. It's usefulness is that it indicates that the potential for current flow exists and that, if a load is connected and it still lights, current should flow.

To monitor current you would use a clamp-on current meter. Provided that there are no earth-faults on the circuit then the current reading on the live will be exactly the same as the current reading on the neutral. (What goes in must come out.)